# Send GPRS data from beagleboard to my web server

Tags: webserver, beagleboard

I have a beagleboard connected to GPS and GSM/GPRS. I have to send GPS coordinates through GPRS on some web server on remote computer. I don't understand how to send data to some localhost web sever? Is it possible?

Thanks